# smooth scroll and open tabs

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

First time using the board, so hope you can understand.

I'm working in wordpress, using visual composer and virgo revolution slider.

I want to make a smooth scroll on a layer in revolution slider, that scrolls down and opens a tab.

I can get it to smooth down, but not open a tab OR jump down and open a tab, but not both..

The page im testing on: http://blackthis.com/clients/acrimo/portfolio/pergolamarkiser/

The button is 'Læs mere' in the slider and should open #acrimo7700 or #acrimo7500.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do i make a smooth scroll that also opens the tab? 
Right now i can make a smooth scroll, but it does not open the tab or i can make a jump, that opens the tab. Not both.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional event on click of your link.

This will work :

```
jQuery('.tp-caption').on('click', function(){
    window.location.hash=jQuery(this).attr('href');
});
```

But for smooth scrolling you need to use setTimeout function to your scroll event which can delay scrolling for little time and meanwhile tab can change first.

Comment: Hey thanks for heltping, but it does not seem to work.

I added the code, and made a 'click' to simple link with delay on 500 and it still just jumps down..